# How to use useContext in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

I'm trying to persist information between different pages using nextjs and the useContext hook in nextjs. But even though I change a variable in a page, when I navigate to another page the variable comes back to its default value.

Here's how the directory structure and _app.tsx look like:

[image]

```
//pages/_app.tsx
import { AppProvider } from '../context/AppContext.js';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AppProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Here's context/AppContext.js simplified

```
'use client';
import React, {useState, useReducer, useContext} from 'react'
import reducer from './reducer'; 

const DISPLAY_ALERT = 'SHOW ALERT';

export const initialState = {
    showAlert:false
}

const AppContext = React.createContext();

   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

   const displayAlert = () => {
       dispatch({type: DISPLAY_ALERT})
    }
    return <AppContext.Provider value={{...state, displayAlert}}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  
}
export const useAppContext = () =>  {
   return useContext(AppContext)
}
```

Here's a simplified context/reducer.js

```
import { initialState } from "./AppContext";

const DISPLAY_ALERT = 'SHOW ALERT';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case DISPLAY_ALERT:
            return {
                ...state,
                showAlert: true
            }
    throw new Error(`no such action! ${action.type}`)
}

export default reducer;
```

So, inside a login_button component, I try to change the default value of showAlert from false to true

```
  import { Button } from "@mui/material";
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import { useAppContext } from '../../../context/AppContext';
  const {showAlert, displayAlert} = useAppContext();

  //...component code...
  
  //this should change showAlert from false to true and, in fact, it does, but when I navigate to '/tela-aluno' by clicking in this button, the showAlert variable goes back to false.
  useEffect(() => displayAlert())
    return <Button  href="tela-aluno"  style={buttonStyle}>Sign in</Button>;
```

Then I use  `const {showAlert} = useAppContext();` in the tela-aluno page and log it to the console and can see it is false.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [DO NOT use images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question.

Comment: @AmitMohanty fixed

Comment: Please, show the code of the context provider and how you call to change the variable on the page.

Comment: @yondemon added more code, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The code you shared is somewhat limited. It does not show how the context is actually used. The shared context is in the context provider, which has to be a level higher than the two pages that share the context. The pages that share the context should have a `useContext` to access the context.

This is a bit of a guess since the information provided is limited.